# Form without errors returns no value

Tags: playframework-2.0, japid

I have some problem with getting the value from the form object.

1. I'm handling the GET request. This generates form with predefined values:

   ```
   Form<ModelObject> form = form(ModelObject.class).fill(new ModelObject());
   return renderJapid(form);
   ```
2. In template I have defined parameter which takes `Form<ModelObject>` and it is named 'form'. On the page are only standard html input boxes like:

   ```
   <input type="text" id="fieldName" name="fieldName" value="$form.apply("fieldName").value()">
   ```
3. After submitting this form I handle this POST request with another method:

   ```
   Form<ModelObject> form = form(ModelObject.class).bindFromRequest();
   if (form.hasErrors()) {
           //render the form again with errors
      } else {
        ModelObject mo = form.get(); // NO-VALUE ERROR
   }
   ```

   Each time I get no-value error on marked line where I want to get the object from form. Do you have any ideas where could be the problem? (Pre-filled data are displayed and even the form object after submission has correct data but no-value)

Comment: Can you verify (example with Chrome Devtools) that values are sent to server?

Comment: I even start server in debug mode and the values are there after the bind process: form.data() are filled, data.errors() are empty and value is None. Its strange, because same code forks fine with another model class. Maybe problem is in ModelObject.class but it only contains public properties with annotations which define constraints. So I don't understand where the problem could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly I solved my problem. The problem was caused by my GenericModel class (each model class extends from this class) which has method `public boolean validate()`. When I removed this method everything worked fine. I know that this method is called by Play for my own custom validations on object, but I still don't understand why this changes the form value to `None`.